# Scheduled Task PowerShell or CMD script - "Run As Administrator"

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I've created a PowerShell script which lists the scheduled tasks and the `LastRunResult`. I'm using `Get-ScheduledTask` command. I need to put it at the end of every scheduled task to send a notification related to the `LastRunResult`.

The problem is that `Get-ScheduledTask` command doesn't work properly and do not show ALL scheduled tasks but just some of them. To be able to see all scheduled tasks the `Get-ScheduledTask` command needs to be run from the CMD or PowerShell console with administrative privileges. And it works from there. But it doesn't work when I run such script from Task Scheduler. Checking `Run with highest privileges` doesn't work. Specifying `Policy -Bypass` doesn't work as well.

Does anyone know how to execute `Get-ScheduledTask` from Task Scheduler ran in administrator mode to list all scheduled tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused if you have UAC enabled or are logged on as a user who is not an administrator.
Ensure the runas account is a local administrator.